# Connotation of "for" / "for the"

Tags: grammaticality, articles, writing-style

I asked [this question on ELL](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/344811/trouble-between-for-and-for-the) and got a satisfactory answer about whether "A new material for manufacture of bricks" is a correct title for a scientific article.

However, it seems that ELL is a place for asking about correctness, not style. My question is thus:
between, say,

> A new material for the manufacture of bricks

and

> A new material for manufacture of bricks

is there a change in connotation due to "for" vs "for the"?

Comment: The style point made on ELL wasn't about those two: the second was ruled out as ungrammatical. The style choice was between the first example and "A new material for manufacturing bricks."

Comment: Have you tried to check  relative frequencies of use (say using Google ngrams) for 'for manufacture of bricks/glass/iron/...' vs 'for the manufacture of bricks/glass/iron/...', Sardine? The definite article seems to be the idiomatic choice, and examples without it tend to be in the stilted language of technical journals / ads. I'd say that 'ungrammatical' is over-prescriptive for not doing, but the article is usually better included.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth FF's answer on ELL does that. I agree that 'ungrammatical' is a bit much, but for a learner, it's a good example where the omission of 'the' is unusual.

Comment: In a formal title, you don't need the: **A New Material for Brick Manufacturing**. manufacture of bricks is heavy.

Comment: @Lambie that's good: even 'A New Material for Brick Manufacture'.

Comment: @WeatherVane You're the English speaker here, but I understood they said both are valid: "I don't think the article-less version is actually syntactically invalid".

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Thanks for the tip, I have and it varies depending on what comes before. The article is most common (often by far) but adding "A method for..." seems to slightly favour omiting the article. So both seem to be in use.

Comment: @Lambie I see, however in my case I'm not sure that would work. There is an adjective before, e.g. a new method for the exact computation. Would you use "for directly computing"?

Comment: It depends on the context: a title may omit articles and and prepositions, but if the title tries to be a proper sentence, then it should be.

Comment: Now your adding something??

Comment: @Sardine You need to give us the precise example you're talking about.

Comment: The one without the article does not display idiomatic usage.